# Making Lists the same size

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of lists that contains temperature data; however, sometimes a probe disconnects when I am trying to collect data and for example, pandas will complain:

```
ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 4 columns
```

so if I have a list of list such as `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]` how can I make it such that the list becomes `[[1, 2, 3, X, X], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]` or if I had six sensors and the output was [[1, 1], [2, 2]] it becomes `[[1, 1, X, X, X, X], [2, 2, X, X, X, X]]`.

In short, I would like to make each list the same size N and populate cells with an `X`

Edit: The fill will always occur at the end of the list

Comment: Will the fill *aways* be at the end of the list, regardless of when the dropout actually occurred? What determines the length of the lists? Please **update the question** to address these questions.

Comment: @S3DEV yes - the sensors populate the lists sequentially and if the first one drops out based on my schematic all the others will

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add to your sublists the missing elements, for example:

```py
NUMBER_OF_SENSORS = 6
data = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]

new_data = [l + ["X"] * (NUMBER_OF_SENSORS - len(l)) for l in data]

print(new_data)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 1, "X", "X", "X", "X"], [2, 2, "X", "X", "X", "X"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Bulkier but also more flexible solution

```
def fill (list_name, cap):
    while len (list_name) < cap:
        list_name.append ('x')
```